# missing last data when exporting gridview to excel

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

When I exporting gridview to excel there's missing data which is the last.
Here is my code in exporting data.

```
private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 1; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

this is the code for the button.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents  (.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
            ToCsV(gvHistory, sfd.FileName); // Here dataGridview1 is your grid view name 
        }
```

Comment: Bad idea to use a big-ass string, so firstly use `StringBuilder`.
Secondly, write to the `Stream` and `.Flush` as you are going, dont forget to empty the `StringBuilder`.
Thirdly, `RowCount` is wrong, use a `foreach` so that you dont have to choose the counter, (`foreach` is also faster), and then you can test `if(DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow)` if you have the blnak entry row in your `DataGridView`

Comment: what about for (int i = 0; i < **dGV.RowCount - 1**; i++)? Should it be for (int i = 0; i < **dGV.RowCount**; i++)

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
  ...
}
```

So you explicitly exclude the last row from the export.
Change `i < dGV.RowCount - 1` to `i < dGV.RowCount`.

---

Additionally, the code:

```
string stLine = "";
for (int j = 1; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
  stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
```

Is basically an example when to use `StringBuilder` instead of `string`. It will get progressively slower as you get more rows. The better version is:

```
StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
   sbOutput.AppendLine(Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t");
for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = 1; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
    sbOutput.Append(Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t");
  sbOutput.AppendLine();
}
Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(sbOutput.ToString());
```

---

Next, when iterating over a collection, you can use the `for(int i=0; i < length; i++)` pattern, but it's usually better to simply use a `foreach`. That way you are sure that it *will* loop all the rows - that's what a foreach does by definition. The added benefit is that the loop variable has a much nicer name, i.e. `row` instead of `dGV.Rows[i]`. So the code will be:

```
foreach(var column in dGV.Columns)
   sbOutput.AppendLine(Convert.ToString(column.HeaderText) + "\t");

foreach (var row in dGV.Rows)
{
  foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
    sbOutput.Append(Convert.ToString(cell.Value) + "\t");
  sbOutput.AppendLine();
}
Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(sbOutput.ToString());
```

which is way more readable and way less prone to silly 'off-by-one' errors.

---

Lastly, a nitpicking point: the method is called `ToCsv`, but the values are not comma-separated, but tab-separated values. It's not much of an offense, because, somehow, the term "CSV" has evolved to mean any format where rows are on separate lines, and the values in the row are *somehow* separated, but still, tab-separated values is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<=` in the loops instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're cutting off the last item in the dGV.

```
    // Export data.
    for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
```

should be

```
    // Export data.
    for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount; i++)
```